# how to do select more then 3 table add in select IN function

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, U.l_name
 FROM posts M, person U
 WHERE M.uid_fk=U.p_id
    AND M.uid_fk in (
      (select send_id from friend_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1)
        or
     (select p_id from friend_request where send_id = '7' AND status=1) 
        AND
     (select send_id from follower_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1 AND M.uid_fk = '7')
        AND 
     M.uid_fk = 7
  )
 order by M.post_id DESC
```

and made by i can't got current data.

how to i get like this query

```
SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, U.l_name
 FROM posts M, person U
 WHERE M.uid_fk=U.p_id
  AND M.uid_fk in (1,2,3,4,7,8,9)
 order by M.post_id DESC
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i can't got current data"? Is there any error message involved? Are you sure that all conditions match properly?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: As far as I see, the condition in the middle is a complete mess. Yo u cannot use such conditions that put some `OR` or `AND` within a `IN` clause

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, I guess you want to get posts data which has entries in friend_request or follower_request tables. If that's what you mean then you could use UNION for your query:

```
SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, 
U.l_name
FROM posts M, person U
WHERE 
   M.uid_fk = 7
   AND M.uid_fk=U.p_id
   AND M.uid_fk in (select send_id from friend_request where p_id = M.uid_fk AND 
   status=1)

UNION ALL

SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, 
U.l_name
FROM posts M, person U
WHERE 
   M.uid_fk = 7
   AND M.uid_fk=U.p_id
   AND M.uid_fk in (select p_id from friend_request where send_id = M.uid_fk AND 
   status=1) 

UNION ALL

SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, 
U.l_name
FROM posts M, person U
WHERE 
   M.uid_fk = 7
   AND M.uid_fk=U.p_id
   AND M.uid_fk in (select send_id from follower_request where p_id = M.uid_fk AND 
   status=1)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

Comment: i got error #1250 - Table 'M' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list

Comment: oh, ok. just edit the following statement :ORDER BY M.post_id DESC to become : ORDER BY post_id DESC. I've edited my previous answer.

Comment: i don't get any data. empty data

Comment: Well, my previous answer handles the IN statement problem the you are facing. Regarding that you get empty data I can help with that issue if you post your tables and sample tables data, and your expected result set.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know what you actually intend but this may help.

```
SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, U.l_name
FROM posts M
INNER JOIN person U ON M.uid_fk=U.p_id
WHERE  M.uid_fk = 7
AND  ( 
           M.uid_fk in (select send_id from friend_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1)
        OR M.uid_fk in (select p_id from friend_request where send_id = '7' AND status=1)
        )
AND M.uid_fk in(select send_id from follower_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1)
ORDER BY M.post_id DESC
```

You can't include OR *inside* `in()` but you can join two `in()`s by an OR

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY M.post_id DESC LIMIT 0, 25' at line 10

Comment: There was a parentheses missing, that is now corrected.